# Migrate Jira to MySql - Unknown system variable 'storage_engine'

Tags: mysql, jira

I'm trying to setup Jira on a vm.
I want to move from the embedded `H2` database to my own `mysql` database.

I'm currently running `mysql 5.7.x` on `ubuntu 16.04`. However when I try to connect Jira with this server I get the following error message:

```
Unknown system variable 'storage_engine'
```

I already tried a number of things to fix this. First off in my `mysql.cnf` file I added `default-storage-engine = InnoDB` This didn't do anything for the error.

On my Jira vm I went into `/opt/atlassian/jira/atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/database-defaults`

and changed it to

```
databaseUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost/jira?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true&sessionVariables=default-storage-engine=InnoDB
```

as well as

```
databaseUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost/jira?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true
```

Again nothing changed for the error.
I also went into the dbconfig.xml file and removed the `sessionVariables=storage-engine=InnoDB` part from the url. Again this didn't change anything.

I've also tried changing it to `sessionVariables=default-storage-engine=InnoDB`

Again no luck.

Does anyone have an idea how to get it to work? I don't want to create another sql setup just to run sql 5.6.x to be honest. I hope someone knows the solution to this.

Comment: What did Atlassian support say?

Comment: @EEAA To be honest I didn't even think about that. I've just been trying to figure it out myself

Comment: Atlassian support has been moderately to willingly helpful to us - give them a shout.

Comment: Yup, agreed. In my experience they're quite helpful, as long as you're not trying to deviate from how they think things should be done.

Comment: I'm contacting support right now. However lira currently doesn't support 5.7.x so I hope they are willing to suggest work arounds

Comment: They'll probably suggest using MySQL 5.6

Comment: Should be no reason JIRA would not work with 5.7. I think you must have issues with the startup phase. Post the relevant MySQL error log. The initial error looks like a bad variable name in the my.cnf file. If you alter values in the config file you need to restart MySQL ( and check the error log after startup)

Answer (score 1):

This question is answered in [the atlassian community website](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/JIRA-Core-questions/Unknown-system-variable-default-storage-engine-when-attempting/qaq-p/60963).

The workaround is to uninstall MySQL 5.1 and install MySQL 5.6